# Unity3d, Appodeal, GooglePlayServices And Androit 65k method Limit

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-services, appodeal

I'm having a problem trying to use Appodeal with GooglePlayServices and Unity3d, here are my steps:

1 - Import the GooglePlayServices package;

2 - Import the Appodeal package

3 - Compile the project.

Then the error:

CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed
...
...
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong

Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithDexForRelease'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
>   ...
>   ...

This is about the android 65k methods limits. Right?

There is a way to solve this without having to use Proguard or export my project to Android Studio?

Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Appodeal Support, i solved my problem:

1- Remove mmedia and inmobi folders from plugins/android.

2- Before initiliazation code of sdk, write:

```
    Appodeal.disableNetwork("mmedia");
    Appodeal.disableNetwork("inmobi");
```

my project was built perfectly after that